# What does it mean to "survive oneself?"

Tags: idioms

I just can't realize what it means to "survive oneself?"

Please help.

Comment: What does it mean to survive?

Comment: Context in which you've seen this fragment would be helpful.

Comment: To be unsuccessful at self-sabotage? In the extreme form, to fail at taking your own life?

Answer (score 2):

An educated guess would be surviving those moments where you might be your own worst enemy, where your thoughts are putting you down and you getting past them. So *surviving oneself* might mean that surviving the negative thoughts that arise by your own doing and are not directly related to some external event.

I am linking below some articles I found online that support this guess.

- http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-survive%20oneself.html
- https://www.theodysseyonline.com/survival-101-survive-saltiest-days

Hope this helps.